# Image with correct path doesn't show in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I have this following UI:
[image]

After I click on the listbox to the left where it says "Vienna Tour"; on the right it should show an image. I have binded the image source the following way:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding (vm:MainViewModel.AddTourViewModel).SelectedTour.RouteImage, Converter={StaticResource AddTourViewModel}}"/>
```

The problem I have now is, the image path is correct but in the UI the image itself is not showing.

This is how I convert the image in my viewmodel:

```
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value != null
                ? new BitmapImage() { UriSource = new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.Relative) }
                : new BitmapImage() { UriSource = new Uri("error.jpg", UriKind.Relative) };

        }
```

The value after clicking "Vienna Tour" points to the image path as you can see on the following picture:

[image]

Comment: check the size of the Image control (make sure it has the size you expect ). You can set a fixed image source instead of binding to see if it is displayed correctly

Comment: @AmoRobb Yes. when used a fixed source the image shows. And changing the size unfortunately did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitmapImage implements the `ISupportInitialize` interface, which means that when you initialize a BitmapImage by settings its `UriSource` property, you have to call the `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` methods.

For convenience, there is a constructor with an `Uri` parameter:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value != null 
        ? new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.Relative)) 
        : new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"error.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Alternatively, use the BitmapFrame class:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value != null 
        ? BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.Relative)) 
        : BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(@"error.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Clemens at this point i think it would have been better to just add a new answer as this adds a whole lot more detail to my original answer and uses a different apporach. Still learned something new, apprecieate it.